# Back button closes app instead of going to previous fragment android navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

While creating a very simple sample app, I couldn't wrap my head around why my app is closing when I press the hardware back button on my emulator.

I have 1 mainActivity and 2 fragments.

When I am on the NavigationFragment and press back, the app closes instead of going back to IntermediateFragment.

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.exampleapplication.MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

navigation_graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav"
    app:startDestination="@+id/intermediateFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/intermediateFragment"
        android:name="com.exampleapplication.IntermediateFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_intermediate_to_navigation"
            app:destination="@+id/navigationFragment"
            />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigationFragment"
        android:name="com.exampleapplication.NavigationFragment"
        />
</navigation>
```

IntermediateFragment:

```
class IntermediateFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_intermediate, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        btn_next_fragment.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_intermediate_to_navigation)
        }
    }
}
```

NavigationFragment:

```
class NavigationFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        btn_first_library.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().setGraph(R.navigation.first_library_nav)
        }

        btn_download_pdf.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().setGraph(R.navigation.download_pdf_nav)
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you calling `setGraph` in `NavigationFragment`? That's going to reset everything.

Comment: It's just to go to my next graph which is defined in a separate module, but this isn't the concern because it's only called when clicking on a button. I want to know why the app closes when I press back on that fragment

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're missing one line on your `<fragment>`:

```
app:defaultNavHost="true"
```

As per the [Navigation Getting Started guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhostfragment):

> The `app:defaultNavHost="true"` attribute ensures that your `NavHostFragment` intercepts the system Back button.

Since you don't set that, Navigtion does not intercept the back button and hence, you only get the default activity behavior (which is closing your activity).

Comment: tnx bro. it helped me.

Comment: didn't work for me I have 3 tabs on the main page and all other frags use the same activity I only want back arrows on any of the sub tabs details and go back but it closes app for me too

Comment: @JPM - the [action bar guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration) specifically tells you how to hide the Up arrow on multiple destinations (i.e., all of your 3 tabs).